# local variable output into another function

Tags: python

I generate a 'guess' and 'answer' in two functions. How do I pass these specific results into a subsequent function that uses 'guess' and 'answer' in its argument?

```
import random

def generate_guess():
    guess = input("Please enter a 4 digit guess: ")
    print(guess) 
    return guess


def generate_secret():
    while True:
        num = random.randint(0,9999)
        num = str(num)
        if num[0:1] != num[1:2]:
            if num[0:1] != num[2:3]:
                if num[0:1] != num[3:4]:
                    if num[1:2] != num[2:3]:
                        if num[1:2] !=num[3:4]:
                            if num[2:3] != num[3:4]:
                                secret = num
                                print(secret)
                                answer = secret
                                return answer
                                break

def how_many(answer,guess):
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `how_many(generate_secret(), generate_guess())`. If the answer isn't supposed to change, try doing this:

```
secret = generate_secret
while <user has not guessed the answer>
    how_many(secret, generate_guess())
```

Also your `generate_secret` function is purely frightening. Try going to code review to fix up that function please; it looks very inefficient and unreadable.

Comment: how_many(answer,guess) must stay the same. Can't be reformatted (assignment specifics)

Comment: @S.G.Radcliffe I'm not telling you to change `how_many(answer, guess)`...